# How to manage data in a iOS app

Tags: objective-c, constructor

I'm developing an app where I have some data. It would be some strings I want to use.
The issue is I would like to initialize with the data of a file. something like:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) Cow *cow;
_cow = [[Cow alloc] init (NSString *) @"Some string"];
```

I have the proper constructor for cow that accepts an string .
What I want is the way I can initialize severals cows with different strings and repeat some values if I want.

I was thinking in a text file where I have all the strings, and just pick those I want.
Another possibility is a db like SQlite.

Comment: I think you should read more about obj-c language. Anyway try it: Cow *cow = [[Cow alloc] initWithString:@"cowName"]; Cow *cow2 = [[Cow alloc] initWithString:@"secondCowName"];

Comment: I didn't mean that. Sorry. What I want is something like a db where I choose the data I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your object Cow conform to a NSCoding protocol:

```
//Cow.h file
@interface Cow : NSObject <NSCoding>
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *someString;
@end

//Cow.m
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _someString = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"someString"];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
    [aCoder encodeObject:self.someString forKey:@"someString"];
}
```

And after that you can save it to a file (you can create array of Cow objects and save it to a file):

```
NSrray *data = @[cow1, cow2, cow3];
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:data toFile:[self pathToFile]];
```

And you can read it like that:

```
    NSFileManager* fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[self pathToData]])
    {
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[self pathToData]];
        NSMutableArray *dataArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
        // dataArray -> array with your data
    }
```

Hopefully I understood your question.

**//EDITED**

Get file to path:

```
-(NSString*)pathToData
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyData"];

    NSFileManager* fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filePath])
    {
        [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:filePath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil];
    }

    return [filePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"mydata.plist"];
}
```

Save and remove data:

```
-(BOOL)save
{
    NSMutableArray *data = [self cachedDataFromFile];
    if (!data)
    {
        NSLog(@"data = nil");
        data = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:@[self]];
    }
    else
        [data addObject:self];

    return [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:data toFile:[self pathToData]];
}

-(void)removeFromFile
{
    NSMutableArray *data = [self cachedDataFromFile];
    if (!data)
        return;
    else
    {
        [data removeObject:self];
        [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:data toFile:[self pathToData]];
    }
}

-(NSMutableArray*)cachedDataFromFile
{
    NSFileManager* fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[self pathToData]])
    {
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[self pathToData]];
        NSMutableArray *dataArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];

        return dataArray;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Let me know is it work for you.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is much more want I want. But I still have a question. Do I have to create all the data when I run the application?
Actually read the data is really helpful, but how can I create it just once?

Comment: I don't know what are yours requirements. You can create a new data (Cow object) when you need it and after that you can read existing data from a file and you can append new object to the data and save it again? is that something you want to do? To get the object by a name you can read the array from a file and filter your array (NSPredictate)

Comment: Exactly that is what I want, but I was googling for how to create this data file and I found nothing. Do you know how to create and manage this data file?

Answer (score 2):

Reading your comments to other answers, it seems that you are interested in an object graph persistence mechanism for your application.  The answer given by @Greg - object graph serialization - is excellent.  In the default case, you'd be reading your entire object graph into memory, which may or may not be what you want.  (There are ways of dealing with that too.)  You asked about how to choose data you want.  In the case where your `Cow`'s are in memory, you can find your `Cow` of choice in a lot of ways.  For example:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Cow : NSObject
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString *color;
@end

@implementation Cow
@end

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        Cow *brownCow = [Cow new];
        brownCow.color = @"brown";

        Cow *whiteCow = [Cow new];
        whiteCow.color = @"white";

        NSArray *cows = @[brownCow,whiteCow];

        NSUInteger cowIndex = [cows indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(Cow *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
                return [[obj color] isEqualToString:@"brown"];
        }];
        if( cowIndex != NSNotFound )
            NSLog(@"Your brown cow is: %@",cows[cowIndex]);
        else
            NSLog(@"No brown cow");
    }
}
```

But there are other object persistence frameworks that you may consider.  For example, [Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/cdProgrammingGuide.html) is commonly used.  sqlite3 is another possibility, which when used with an object-oriented abstraction layer like [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) is another good choice.

The answer boils down to your requirements.  How many `Cow` objects might there be?  What are the performance requirements?  And so on.